# how can I get the rubymine/intellij rails debugger to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, intellij-idea, rubymine

I created a new app with rubymine and try to debug a rails app but get "no frames available". How can I get this to work?

latest version of ruby, rails and rubymine. Also fails with intellij.

[image]

I know the breakpoint is being triggered because when I have the breakpoint the response never arrives.
I just see in the debugger page "frames are not available".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to make it work here https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4411325391762-Debugging-with-2-6-8

I disabled the ruby experimental debugger and it started working:

[image]

Comment: I can't find the setting to disable "use experimental debugger". where can i find that? i'm using rubymine 2022.1.3

Comment: There are now two different registry keys `ruby.use.debase23.debugger` and `ruby.use.debase30.debugger`, so I guess it now supports ruby 3